# Creating an Array of Strings from miscro SD Arduino

Tags: arrays, string, arduino

I'm involved in a project where i need to READ data from a "csv" file and then i need to storage this information in an Array of Strings in order to search, write, delete and add information after the storage. The fields that i handle from a "csv" file are:

ID, Name, amount:

1234    Mario   $100
3245  Francisco $15.50
4356    Jorge   $0.00
4321    Pablo   $0.00
2346    Rene    $0.00
8795    Sofia   $233.20
3569    Sandra  $0.00
8907    Andrea  $0.00
6890    Maru    $0.00
4563    Ana $0.00
6789    Noemi   $23.12
    FINAL

The problems is when i create the Array of Strings, always write in the current cells that an index points (what is right) but overwrite too the previous cells (what is not correct), example:

step 0:
cell0: 1234 Mario   $100

step1:
cell0:3245  Francisco   $15.50
cell1:3245  Francisco   $15.50

step3:
cell0:4356  Jorge   $0.00
cell1:4356  Jorge   $0.00
cell2:4356  Jorge   $0.00

and so on...

As you can infer in the end i have all the Array of Strings's cells with the last information, 6789 Noemi   $23.12 and not with the correct information. The code is:

```
#include <SD.h>

//Ajustes SPI
//MOSI, MISO, SCLK estan predeterminados
int CS_pin=8;

char in_char=0;
String datosSD="";

int x=0;
char myStrings[60];
char* arrayStrings[13];  

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);    //Se inicializa velocidad de comunicación serial
Serial.println("Inicializando microSD");

pinMode(CS_pin,OUTPUT);  //Se configura Pin CS (8) como salida

  //Se verifica si la tarjeta esta lista
  if(!SD.begin(CS_pin))
  {
    Serial.println("Fallo microSD");
    return;
  }
   Serial.println("miscroSD lista");

  //Se abre un archivo para escribir en el
  //Solo un archivo se puede abrir a la vez
  File datoArchivo=SD.open("TEST.csv");
  in_char=datoArchivo.read();

//Se verifica si la apertura del archivo tuvo éxito para poder escribir en el archivo
if(datoArchivo)
{ 
    while(datoArchivo.available())
    {
      if(in_char!='\n')
      {
        datosSD.concat(in_char);
        in_char = datoArchivo.read();
      }
      else
         {
           Serial.println(datosSD);              
           datosSD.toCharArray(myStrings, 60);  
           arrayStrings[x]=myStrings;
           x++;

             in_char = datoArchivo.read();
             datosSD="";
       }  
    } 
   datoArchivo.close(); 
}
else
  {
    Serial.println("No se pudo Accesar al Archivo");
  } 
/////////// Show the information of Array of Strings /////////////////    
 for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
 {
  Serial.println(arrayStrings[i]);
  delay(100);
 }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
}

void loop()
{ 
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have only allocated one string, not the 13 you think.  This creates the array of char pointers you needed:

```
char* arrayStrings[13];
```

But those are just the pointers, not the strings themselves.  You have only one of these, which is the actual string:

```
char myStrings[60];
```

You keep re-using that one string for reading from the file.  You assign all the array of pointers to this same one string:

```
arrayStrings[x]=myStrings;
```

So when you walk the list of pointers and print them, you get the same one last string read from the file.  If you printed, the actual pointer value, this would become clear.  Try this, and note what you see:

```
Serial.println( (int)(arrayStrings[i]) );
```

To make this work, you need to allocate memory for all the strings you intend to keep in memory.

And this is where this becomes an excellent learning problem.  You will consume almost half available RAM trying to perform any operations on this data set in memory.  Add a little more data, or complexity of operations on the data and you will not be able to perform operations on the data with everything held in RAM.  This will change into a problem of how to keep all the data on disk (SD card), and perform operations in memory just on small amounts, similar to how a database operates.

Comment: I understand now what happen with the code, the index "x" changes but the string is always the same, so every pointer points to the same address at the end. You are right, what i try to do is a some kind of database but i need to change my strategy. I am planing to know the position of each data in the "csv" file so as to write/overwrite/delete information when i find the data and not storage all the information in RAM, can you give me some hints to perform this operation?, the problem is how to know the exact  data's position in "csv" file. Thank you in advance @jdr5ca.

Answer (score 0):

Try using String mystrings[] instead, it has worked nicely for me, though it is not as memory efficient as jdr5ca's answer. However, since he is probably right and you are going to have to read only pieces at a time, that should not be a problem. Take a look at http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject
for help using String and
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/String
for more information if you need the extra data storage.

Comment: If i use "String mySatring" there will be an error in the program, because of the "arrayStrings[x]=myStrings", arrayStrings is a type "char* ", is a mismatch, thank you for the links.